# Will existing apps built with build.phonegap continue to work after Adobe discontinue's build.phonegap service?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-cli

We have created some iOS apps with build.phonegap. Our developer license with Apple doesn't expire till next year. Will the iOS apps we have already built with build.phonegap continue to work even if after Adobe discontinues build.phonegap in October 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing apps should still work -- it's just that we can't use the service anymore to build updates, or point users to a patch hosted on build.phonegap.com.

For new releases / patch fixes, it's either:

- Use Cordova's CLI to build locally / in-house (free).
- Migrate the build to Ionic's AppFlow service (https://ionicframework.com/appflow), and negotiate a price with the Ionic crew.
- Migrate to another framework -- the post mentions Monaca & Onsen UI, Framework7, NativeScript, Ionic Capacitor, Progressive Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses features Apple has deprecated, you'll need to rebuild using a modern tool. Things like UIWebView will cause problems.

Also, add [VoltBuilder](https://volt.build) to the list of alternatives.